# How do I check if a value( numeric value) appears n times consecutively across columns A0 to A37 and gives the value of n in SAS?

Tags: count, sas

I have a data that looks like this
[image]

I need something like this [image: Column I gives the number of times values in Column MAX appears consecutively across columns A0 to A10]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do not post data as photographs.  It is impossible to use in code when shared that way.  What did you try?  How did it not do what you wanted?

Comment: For 3 why is I 7, shouldn't it be 6?

Comment: I want to check if it has occured consecutively. So for 3, value 16 appears consecutively 6 times from A5 to A10

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you are wanting to do, but when you want to look across variables in a data set [Arrays](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsref/p08do6szetrxe2n136ush727sbuo.htm) are your best friend. After reviewing the documentation, look for any of the great papers posted on how to use Arrays.
Update your question for a more specific response.

Answer (score 0):

Please type out your data in the future, ideally as shown below. This shows how you can capture a streak.

```
data have;
    input Name A0-A10 MAX;
    cards;
1 10 9 12 12 12 12 12 11 12 12 9 12
2 45 67 23 67 9 45 67 67 67 67 67 67
3 12 14 1 16 14 16 16 16 16 16 16 16
4 14 56 7 68 94 35 67 342 252 253 35 342 
;
    ;
    ;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    *declare array to loop;
    array A(0:10) A0-A10;
    *use a counter to keep track of consecutive values;
    counter=0;
    *use a variable to keep track of the largest streak;
    max_streak=0;

    *loop start;
    do i=0 to 10;

        *if value matches maximum increase the counter;
        if A(i)=max then
            counter+1;

        *if streak is larger than the largest streak replace the largest streak;
        if counter>max_streak then
            max_streak=counter;

        *set streak back to 0 if value does not match maximum;
        if A(i) ne max then
            counter=0;
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data have;
input Name A0-A10 MAX;
datalines;
1 10 9  12 12 12 12 12 11  12  12  9  12  
2 45 67 23 67 9  45 67 67  67  67  67 67  
3 12 14 1  16 14 16 16 16  16  16  16 16  
4 14 56 7  68 94 35 67 342 252 253 35 342 
;

data want(drop = c);
   set have;
   array a a:;
   i = 0; c = 0;

   do over a;
      if a = max  then c + 1;
      if c > i    then i = c;
      if a ne max then  c = 0;
   end;
run;
```

Comment: How is this checking is the value occured consecutively?

Comment: By adding 1 to c if a = max. If it is not, set it to 0.